# Serious issues understanding namespacing in Laravel 5

Tags: laravel, namespaces, laravel-5

I am having problems understanding namespacing. It just feels so stupid that for every Facade or helper I want to include, I need to included it in the controller file.

So, say I have this exerpt of my controller:

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Auction;
use App\Bid;
use App\BidBuy;
use App\Http;
use Redirect;
use Session;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Omnipay\Omnipay;

class PayPalController extends Controller {

    private $data;

    public function getPayment()
    {
        redirectIfNotLoggedIn();
    }
```

The line with `redirectIfNotLoggedIn();` is a function I want to call that is stored in App/Http/helpers.php

This is the file: `helpers.php`

```
<?php namespace App\Http;

class HelperFunctions {
    // Filter for guest only pages
    public function redirectIfLoggedIn() {
        if (Session::has('steamid')) {
            return Redirect::to('/');
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    // Filter for logged users only pages
    public function redirectIfNotLoggedIn() {
        if (Session::has('steamid')) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return Redirect::to('/');
        }
    }
}
```

Back in the controller I have included: `use App\Http;`

When I go to call that function I get this:

```
FatalErrorException in PayPalController.php line 20:
Call to undefined function App\Http\Controllers\redirectIfNotLoggedIn()
```

**EDIT:**

Now I have: `HelperFunctions.php` located at `App/Helpers/HelperFunctions.php`:

```
<?php namespace App\Helpers;

use Session;
use Redirect;

// Filter for guest only pages
function redirectIfLoggedIn() {
    if (Session::has('steamid')) {
        return Redirect::to('/');
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

// Filter for logged users only pages
function redirectIfNotLoggedIn() {
    if (Session::has('steamid')) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return Redirect::to('/');
    }
}
```

Excerpt of `composer.json`:

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "database"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/"
    },
    "psr-0": {
        "Ignited\\LaravelOmnipay": "src/"
    },
    "files": [
        "app/Helpers/HelperFunctions.php"
    ]
},
```

And this is my controller:

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;

//use App\Helpers\HelperFunctions;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Auction;
use App\Bid;
use App\BidBuy;
use Redirect;
use Session;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Omnipay\Omnipay;

class PayPalController extends Controller {

    private $data;

    public function getPayment(\App\Helpers\HelperFunctions $helper)
    {
        $helper->redirectIfNotLoggedIn();
    }

.. rest of the controller code here ..
}
```

Comment: Its a best practice to name your class file its class name, so I suggest you move `class HelperFunctions` to `HelperFunctions.php` file. You could create a folder for the file here: `app/helpers/HelperFunctions.php` , then  to use HelperFunctions class in your controller specify the namespace, `use App\Helpers\HelperFunctions`

Comment: Why do you removed the HelperFunction class itself? Add the `class HelperFunctions...` part

Comment: When I do that, I get a white screen, no error message. I can't tell whats wrong. The function doesn't seem to work. Even if I make the function return text, it doesn't show it

Comment: Do you have added the `class HelperFunction {` part and made the methods public? ( `public function redirectIfNotLoggedIn(...`)

Answer (score 1):

Do not use helpers for this. You are violating pretty much everything related to OOP in doing so.

Instead, use [Middleware](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/middleware).

In your controller, simply require the `auth` middleware:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware("auth");
}
```

You are trying to solve a solved problem. If you need to do something before executing a route/controller method, middleware (the Laravel 5 replacement for route filters) should be used.

You will likely have to customise your own middleware, however, then add it to the middleware array in `app/Http/Kernel.php`. Just use `php artisan make:middleware CustomAuthMiddleware`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use your HelperFunctions via method injection in your controller. Like this:

```
public function getPayment(\App\Http\HelperFunctions $helper)
{
    $helper->redirectIfNotLoggedIn();
}
```

It's not tested.

Comment: Thanks. I've moved HelperFunctions.php to `App/Helpers`. Then I do put the code in your answer into my controller but I get this: `FatalErrorException in HelperFunctions.php line 8:
Cannot redeclare App\Helpers\redirectIfLoggedIn() (previously declared in /var/www/laravel/skinauctions/app/Helpers/HelperFunctions.php:8)`

Comment: You have the HelperFunctions.php in `App/Http`?

Comment: I have moved it to `App/Helpers/HelperFunctions.php`

Comment: And I've tried this: `public function getPayment(\App\Helpers\HelperFunctions $helper)
 {
  $helper->redirectIfNotLoggedIn();
 }`

Comment: But get this: `Cannot redeclare App\Helpers\redirectIfLoggedIn() (previously declared in /var/www/laravel/skinauctions/app/Helpers/HelperFunctions.php:8)`

Comment: This error usually indicates an auto loading problem. Could you Update your first post with the new files and code please?

Comment: I have now added the new files and at the bottom of the OP. Thanks